# Print HTML from database as HTML

Tags: html, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a Laravel 5 application, I have some registers in the database, some of them contains HTML code, for exmple:

```
something<span>Something</span>
<h3>Something</H3>
```

Then, I consult the registers and I'm listing all of them, let suppose that the field name is `description` so, I print this in this way:

```
{{$register->description}}
```

But it's printing the HTML as text, and not like HTML, I also tried

```
{{htmlentities($register->description)}}
```

But with no results, it's still showing the HTML as text. So what others options do I have to achieve this?

Comment: If you think the linked question does not apply please let me know.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes! that totally works